# heap dump generation on websphere

Tags: websphere-8, heap-dump

> I have enabled automatic heap dump generation on Websphere application
> server 8.5.5 by below steps.
>
> Appserver>>process definition>>environment entries
>
> Added below 2 entries.
>
> IBM_HEAPDUMP = TRUE
> IBM_HEAPDUMP_OUTOFMEMORY = TRUE
>
> I just want to know how frequently heap dump will be generated?
> example out of 15 request. 10 request, we have faced outofMemoryerror:
> java heap space. Heap dump will generate for 1 time or 10 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature using environment variables.

The `IBM_HEAPDUMP` is only useful to set to `false` to completely disable heapdumps. Setting it to `true` is redundant because that is the default.

The same is true of `IBM_HEAPDUMP_OUTOFMEMORY`. Taking a heapdump on an OutOfMemoryError is enabled by default.

You can find more information on these environment variables here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/env_j9.html

Note that envars to control dumps are no longer recommended in favor of `-Xdump`: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/dump_agents.html

With that said, there is no such feature as automatically generating heapdumps without some trigger. You can find various way on how to request heapdumps here: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Troubleshooting-Troubleshooting_WebSphere_Application_Server-Troubleshooting_WAS_Traditional.html#Troubleshooting-Troubleshooting_WAS_Traditional-Request_Heap_Dump

The easiest way is probably to script it. You haven't specified which operating system you're on, but I'll guess it's POSIX-based with IBM Java, so I would use Java Surgery with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
  java -jar surgery.jar -command HeapDump -pid $1
  sleep $2
done
```

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=7d3dc078-131f-404c-8b4d-68b3b9ddd07a

Comment: My bad, forgot to mention OS name. Linux.

Thanks for links, really helpful.

Comment: Okay, in the case of IBM Java on Linux, I generally recommend using core dumps instead of PHDs because core dumps are a superset. So to produce a core dump manually, just install gdb and then run `gcore ${PID}`, rename the file with the `.dmp` extension and then load it in the IBM MAT tool: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Major_Tools-IBM_Memory_Analyzer_Tool.html